How can I get a page count of the full URL in the Ruby GA4 client?
I have been trying to query GA4 for page counts using the code below which I got from this article and linked git. I can get results using the dimension "pagePath" but this only gives me the URL before "?". I need the full page URL so this isn't enough. I can get data using the dimension "fullPageUrl" in the GA4 Query Explorer but the API returns no data without errors.
Another issue I notice is that the same query in the query explorer returns 5 times the number of page views returned by the API.
How can I get a count of page views from the ruby GA4 API using the full page URL?
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'google/analytics/data'
require './environment'  # Replace with the path to your environment file
require 'time'

module GoogleAnalytics

  class Report

    attr_reader :metrics
    attr_reader :property_id
    attr_reader :client

    def initialize(metrics: nil, property_id: nil, client: nil)
      @metrics = metrics
      @property_id = property_id || PROPERTY_ID
      @client = client || analytics_data_client
    end

    def get(page_path:, start_date:, end_date:)
      request = GoogleAnalytics::ReportRequest.new(
        page_path: page_path,
        start_date: start_date,
        end_date: end_date,
        property_id: property_id
      ).generate

      client.run_report(request)
    end

    private

    def analytics_data_client
      Google::Analytics::Data.analytics_data do |config|
        config.credentials = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE
      end
    end
  end

  require 'google/analytics/data/v1beta'

  class ReportRequest

    DEFAULT_METRICS = ['screenPageViews'].freeze
    BEGINS_WITH_MATCH_TYPE = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter::StringFilter::MatchType::BEGINS_WITH

    attr_reader :property_id
    attr_reader :page_path
    attr_reader :start_date
    attr_reader :end_date
    attr_reader :metrics

    def initialize(page_path:, start_date:, end_date:, property_id:)
      @page_path = page_path
      @start_date = start_date
      @end_date = end_date
      @property_id = property_id
      @metrics = metrics || DEFAULT_METRICS
    end

    def generate
      Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::RunReportRequest.new(
        property: "properties/#{property_id}",
        # dimensions: [{ name: 'pagePath' }],
        dimensions: [{ name: 'fullPageUrl' }], 
        dimension_filter: dimension_filter(page_path),
        metrics: report_metrics,
        date_ranges: [{ start_date: start_date.to_s, end_date: end_date.to_s }],
      )
    end

    private

    def report_metrics
      metrics.map { |metric| { name: metric } } # DEFAULT_METRICS
    end

    def dimension_filter(page_path)
      {
        filter: {
          field_name: 'fullPageUrl',
          # field_name: 'pagePath',
          string_filter: {
            match_type: BEGINS_WITH_MATCH_TYPE,
            value: page_path,
            case_sensitive: false
          }
        }
      }
    end

  end
end

